# Group row values by the sequence of their appearance

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions

In BigQuery I have a table like this:

| Order | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | A |
| 4 | B |
| 5 | B |
| 7 | A |
| 8 | A |
| 10 | A |
| 11 | C |

The order column is increasing but not continuously in every case. The Value column can have returning values. I need to create groups for the Values by the combination of the value and the number of appearances of the value.
So basically I need a new column (Group) like this:

| Order | Value | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 2 | A | 1 |
| 3 | A | 1 |
| 4 | B | 2 |
| 5 | B | 2 |
| 7 | A | 3 |
| 8 | A | 3 |
| 10 | A | 3 |
| 11 | C | 4 |

I tried to use dense_rank() in different variations, this is the best that I've got, but that's not what I need.

| Order | Value | dense_rank() over(order by Value) | Right solution |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | A | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | A | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | B | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | B | 2 | 2 |
| 7 | A | *1* | *3* |
| 8 | A | *1* | *3* |
| 10 | A | *1* | *3* |
| 11 | C | 4 | 4 |

Code for the test data:

```
with test_data as(
    select 1 as _order, 'A' as value
    union all
    select 2 as _order, 'A' as value
    union all
    select 3 as _order, 'A' as value
    union all
    select 4 as _order, 'B' as value
    union all
    select 5 as _order, 'B' as value
    union all
    select 7 as _order, 'A' as value
    union all
    select 8 as _order, 'A' as value
    union all
    select 10 as _order, 'A' as value
    union all
    select 11 as _order, 'C' as value
)
select _order,
       value,
       dense_rank() over(order by value) value_order,
from test_data
order by _order
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could address this problem with a running count over a computed flag, that has non-null value (1) when there's a change between current "*Value*" and previous "*Value*".

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, 
           CASE WHEN NOT LAG(Value) OVER(ORDER BY Order) = Value THEN 1 END AS change_flag
    FROM tab
)
SELECT order,
       value,
       COUNT(change_flag) OVER(ORDER BY order) + 1
FROM cte
```